# How to show language version in an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have an iOS app where I'm trying to show the current selected language, but also include its variation, i.e. "English (Canada), English (US), ...", as seen in the attached image.

[image]

I am already using the preferred language from Bundle, like so:

```swift
guard let langCode = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first else { return nil }
let locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
guard let language = locale.localizedString(forLanguageCode: langCode)?.localizedCapitalized else { return nil }
```

But I also want to include the variation information (Canada, US, etc). Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: how about `locale.localizedString(forRegionCode:)` and `locale.localizedString(forLanguageCode:)`? You can get both from your locale

Comment: The region is different, you can have the phone set to "English (Canada)" and the region set to France. You would get in this case English for language code and France for region code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer.

Just get the identifier as you normally would from the bundle:

`guard let langCode = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first else { return nil }`

Then use the locale's `localizedString(forIdentifier:)`:
`Locale.autoupdatingCurrent.localizedString(forIdentifier: langCode)`

This will return "English (Canada)" or whatever the language code is, same like in the Settings app.